# Как перебрать массив объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js, объекты

подскажите как перебрать массив объектов? Получаю такой массив объектов, и в моем компоненте нужно сравнить мои данные по id с массивом который приходит с сервера.

Аля, const isDate = ({переменная в которой я получил значение id с json}  === this.$attrs.date)

Подскажите как именно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `for (let i =0; i < array.length; i++) { if ( array[i].id === compareID ) { ... }  }` чем Вас не устраивает?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что именно нужно сделать. Если нужно просто достать объект из массива по id, то достаточно будет использовать метод find

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = [
            { id: 1,
              name: "Artem",
              age: 21
            },
            { id: 2,
              name: "Vova",
              age: 30
            },
            { id: 3,
              name: "Anna",
              age: 24
            }
];

users.map((user) => console.log(user.id + ' ' + user.name + ' ' + user.age))
```

Comment: почему map в данном случае, а не forEach, к примеру?

Comment: Он короче. Всего 3 буквы вместо 7

Comment: map возвращает данные и выделяет под это память

Comment: В этом случае не критично